# What is the typical delay between reporting a murder with a known suspect and arrest?

Tags: united-states, murder, arrest

Note: I am not asking for legal advice here, no rush haha

I was recently looking into the Death of Ahmad Arbery who passed away violently on footage earlier this year. Supposedly it took a few months for the father and son who had chased him to be arrested, despite their clear involvement, whether justified or not.

Similarly, Kyle Rittenhouse was involved in a death of two people in August, and he apparently interacted with police that night, but was not detained and allowed to return to his home state that same night.

Is there a necessary waiting period between a crime being committed and the arrest of someone who is known to be involved but may not be the perpetrator? What is the typical response time? Thanks.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because this is a question of law enforcement practice and not a question regarding the law.

Comment: It could maybe be edited to focus on if there's a necessary waiting period and why it doesn't happen immediately.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Nothing is *typical*

Investigators have wide discretion on how (and if) they pursue an investigation of an alleged crime. When they make an arrest is part of that discretion. Making an arrest starts all sorts of clocks running on the legal process and investigators may not want to do that for all sorts of legitimate reasons.